# Prestashop 1.5.4.1 migration issue

Tags: php, migration, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Hello I am trying to migrate my site from one server to an other, Iive created a backup of all files and BD, uploaded to the new server, change the `settings.inc.php` with the new credentials and when I'm trying to access the site, Prestashop shows me the error.

> Notice: Use of undefined constant _RIJNDAEL_KEY_ - assumed '_RIJNDAEL_KEY_' in /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/classes/Cookie.php on line 78 Notice: Use of undefined constant _RIJNDAEL_IV_ - assumed '_RIJNDAEL_IV_' in /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/classes/Cookie.php on line 78 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/cache/smarty/compile/28/b9/c8/wrt55881070719b54.86654395' in /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(201): Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('/home/admin/dom...', 'compileTemplateSource() #2 /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/classes/module/Module.php(1623): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch() #3 /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/modules/favoriteproducts/favoriteproducts.php(105): ModuleCore->display('/home/admin/dom...', 'favoriteproduct...') #4 /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/classes/Hook.php(421): FavoriteProducts- in /home/admin/domains/bicimaya.mx/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 44

Investigating on Prestashop forums I saw that I have to delete some directories such as `/cache/smarty/cache` and `/cache/smarty/compile`, but my project doesn't have this two directories. I hope anyone can help me to solve this error, thank you.

Comment: Could you please format your error log as code? It's hard to read like this.

Comment: ok, I solved it changing line 80 at file cookie.php like this:

OLD:  $this->_cipherTool = new Rijndael(_RIJNDAEL_KEY_, _RIJNDAEL_IV_);

NEW: $this->_cipherTool = new Rijndael('_RIJNDAEL_KEY_', '_RIJNDAEL_IV_');

Comment: I cleaned your question up some but without more details we probably can't help you. Can you post some configs or describe what you did in your migration?

Answer (score 0):

This module can help migrate from all version to other PrestaShop.
http://addons.prestashop.com/en/8934-migrationpro-migration-prestashop-to-prestashop.html